# I can get it to output HTML text, but I can't get it to display in textbox. What did I do wrong?

Tags: html

This outputs to HTML text:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>practice</title>
    <script type = "text/javascript">   
    function getRestaurant()
    {
      var restaurantList = new Array( "Molinas", "Sonic", "Subway", "McDonalds", "Taco Bell", "Pasanos", "Lone Star Eatery", "Chicken Express" );
      var random = restaurantList[Math.floor(Math.random() * restaurantList.length)];
      document.getElementById( "message" ).innerHTML = random;
     }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><input type = "button" value = "Get Random Restaurant" onclick = "getRestaurant();" /></p>
    <p id = "message" ></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

This has a textbox & button like I need, but the random name does not show up in the textbox.  Can you please direct me in the correct direction?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <head>
    <title>practice</title>
    <script type = "text/javascript">   
        function getRestaurant()
        {
            var restaurantList = new Array ( "Molinas", "Sonic", "Subway", "McDonalds", "Taco Bell", "Pasanos", "Lone Star Eatery", "Chicken Express" );
            var randomR = restaurantList[Math.floor(Math.random() * restaurantList.length)];
            randomR = document.getElementById( "b1" ).value;
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action = "">
        <fieldset>
            <input type = "button" value = "Get Random Restaurant" onclick = "getRestaurant();" />
            <input type = "text" id = "b1" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You forgot last : '}' in second function...

Comment: omg.. I feel like a complete idiot.  Thank you!!!

Comment: http://jsbin.com/tovohoqoko/1/

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning `randomR` the value of `document.getElementById( "b1" ).value`, rather than assigning `document.getElementById( "b1" ).value` the value of `randomR`. Flip it around and it should work :)

```
document.getElementById( "b1" ).value = randomR;
```